# Pre mysql output NOT the same as Update processed in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, string, phpmyadmin

```
$newInt = substr_replace($oldInt, $newDigit, $position, 1);
             $newValue = (string)$newInt;
            echo $newValue;
```

echoes 0000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
   (what i want!)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET $fieldVariable = $newValue WHERE userID  = '".$_SESSION['userID']."' ")or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
```

mysql record shows
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

mysql field is set varchar (100)

Comment: varchar, in that case you should probably put quotes around '$newValue' in your insert statement..

Comment: solved - man that was FAST (3mins) and SPOT ON. (I had only double checked that with double quotes, should've down it in singles.. my newbie error, THANKS AGAIN

Comment: how do i give you a point and mark this as solved??

Comment: @Adam: comments can't be accepted, only "answers".

Comment: I added it as an answer, you may accept it now :-) - edit://wow, that was fast, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add quotes around $newValue, since it is a VARCHAR field

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET $fieldVariable = '$newValue' WHERE userID  = '".$_SESSION['userID']."' ")or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap $newValue in single quotes '{$newvalue}'